# Procedure + Insert

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-cluster

I would like to create a procedure with a while but I have an error.

Here is my procedure:

```
Delimiter //
create procedure procedure1 ()
 BEGIN
Declare i INT;
set i=1;
while i< 74 do
execute immediate 'insert into main values(3,"samples")'
set i=1+1;
end while;
 end //
```

I got this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that on for   the right syntax to use near ''insert into main values(3,"samples")'
```

Someone has an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Change your insert query in procedure like below

```
insert into main values(3,'samples')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use it like this :**
*- store your query into a variable*

```
Delimiter //
create procedure procedure1 ()
 BEGIN
Declare i INT;
v_Sql VARCHAR2(2000);
set i=1;
v_Sql :='insert into main values(3,"samples")';
while i< 74 do
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_Sql ;
set i=1+1;
end while;
 end //
```